# MenuFlyoutItem Get Parent

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, flyout

I have a Flyout attached to a ListView Item, simplified as follows:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel IsHoldingEnabled="True" Holding="ListView_Holding" >
            <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="remove" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click"  />
                </MenuFlyout>
            </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>

private void ListView_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
    FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);

    flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);
}

private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

How do I get the ListView item from within `MenuFlyoutItem_Click` that the MenuFlyout is 'attached' to? I have tried a few things but haven't been able to make it work.

I can post more code if required.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the exact item by getting the DataContext. This will be the object from a collection you're binding to.

```
var datacontext = senderElement.DataContext;
```

Then you can get the ListViewItem from that DataContext.

```
ListViewItem item = this.NameOfYourList.ContainerFromItem(datacontext) as ListViewItem;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, some useful stuff there that I didn't know. 

As I am wanting to execute the code to remove an item from the ListView when the user clicks 'remove' on the flyout, rather than on the long press of the item itself, how do I go about this from within `MenuFlyoutItem_Click`?

Comment: @blawford The datacontext is the item itself (not the ListViewItem but the exact context item). If you're binding ListView.ItemsSource to ObservableCollection, just removing this datacontext from the ListView should immediately reflect in the ListView!